# Change str_replace to preg_replace in SELECT WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a search engine for all posts on my blog.
Initially, my code is:

```
<?php
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['search']);
    $search = str_replace('\'', '', $search);
    $search = str_replace('-', '', $search);
    $search = str_replace('.', '', $search);

    $sqlsearch = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE replace(replace(replace(title, '\'', ''), '-', ' '), '.', '') LIKE '%{$search}%' GROUP BY title");
?>
```

The above script will collect the data in the filtered 'title' column first using 'str replace' and work properly. But I need to create more lists to filter more queries.

So I thought, maybe it could be replaced with 'preg_replace', but not sure yet to apply to my blog.

Could the above script be replaced by this code:

```
<?php
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['search']);
    $search = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u', '', $search);

    $sqlsearch = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u', '', title) LIKE '%{$search}%' GROUP BY title");
?>
```

Please give me the most possible input for me to do. Thank you..

Comment: combining `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` is rarely a good idea: if there are more than one columns, this should produce an error. (unless you suppress it)

Comment: There is no preg_replace function in standard MySQL.

Comment: you could take a look at `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html` and place that in the WHERE. But splitting the search-input into single words and combine it to some `LIKE` parts in the Where clause might be enough.